# What is best practice to save large request and response xml in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, database, sql-server-2008, database-design

I want to save all XML requests and responses in a SQL Server database. These can be in millions. If I use `XML` type in SQL Server it has performance issue.

Can anyone tell me what will be best approach to save such data?

Thanks

Comment: Best way: use the  `XML` datatype, since it has an optimized storage model - it stores XML in a tokenized format, taking up *less storage* than simply storing the XML as `nvarchar(max)` or something like that ...

Comment: it has perfomance issue as i mentioned @marc_s

Comment: ***WHAT*** performance issues? You're not being very clear here ..... it's the most optimized way to store XML inside SQL Server - if that has "performance issues" in your case, then maybe storing these XML inside SQL Server isn't the best option

Comment: The xml can be very big size and can be millions of records in the table. You think storing it as it is will not be an issue? @marc_s

Comment: Listen to @marc_s

Comment: Of course this will be a performance issue. The only way around performance issues with millions of rows are indexes. The XML-index is - in most cases - not the best idea. It might be possible to find a hybrid storage. Store the XML in XML-typed column and extract values you want to search, join, sort after and put them in indexed columns

Comment: Why are you storing these XMLs? How do you intend to use them once they are stored?

Comment: i have to store all the request i made to different apis from my app and its corresponding response. this is just for logging purpose. so if there is any issue i can track down from it. @BrankoDimitrijevic

Comment: @Tahirkheli Then, perhaps, a relational database may not be the best solution - looks like you don't really need the concurrency and safety (and overhead) of a full-blown database. Consider just dumping the log into ordinary file(s), or perhaps using an embedded database... Depending on which language/stack you are using, you'll likely find a logging library that abstracts the log storage away, so you don't even need to worry about that (too much) yourself...

Comment: If you only need to *store* the XML (without actually *using* them inside the database), then maybe think about **compressing** the XML (since it's text, it should compress very handily) and then storing them as **blobs** in a `varbinary(max)` columns ...

Answer (score 0):

I started to write a comment but there was too much for that :)

The right solution may vary, based on what you actually need to do with that data afterwards:

- If you need **just to store** some data in logging purpose you can use simple table with column with XML datatype and some ID, datetime stamps, and maybe some XML based index.
- If you need to **build some reports** based on this data or have an instant fast access to it - the better way is to parse/aggregate all this XML input and store it in proper build database (tables/indexed etc).
- If this requests and responsive have a **massive nature** and this XML has **no specified structure** - consider using some NoSQL solutions.

F.e. we have a search service with logs that are stored:

1. search requests as text,
2. response in xml,
3. also userid, datetime of request start and end.

We got ~500 searches a day, so we store that in one table with index on userid/datetime. All works fine.